# Sobreposição em WEB

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Pessoal eu criei um site, com Wordpress. Porém em uma das páginas quando em mobile meus links não funcionam o que eu entendi era que tinha algo por cima do meu site e quando vi era isso mesmo.Vi que o id #sidebar ocupava todo o site na versão mobile impossibilitando a navegação. Como faço pra 'sobrepor' a ID para atrás do site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode mudar o z-index, que é a camada que define quem fica na frente de outros elementos, assim, se você aumentar o z-index das camadas de trás, elas ficaram sobre a #sidebar. [Entendendo o Z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index)

Outra possível, é você deixar desabilitado a #sidebar nas versões mobile, no css, você cria o média, e muda as propriedades, seria algo como

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar{display: none !important}
}
```

Assim, nos dispositivos com resolução menor que 768px, o #sidebar não apareceria na tela

Comment: Ajudou para caramba, muito obrigado amigo!